# How to set different font sizes within a table?

Tags: tables, fonts

We need tables to present details, thus we need to hight light some information by making a table with different font size within rows table as follows :

[image]

code :

Answer (score 1):

To get this kind of result

[image]

We have to use these font sizes for the specific text, we need to set its one size contain using `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge` and `\Huge` between brackets

code :

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}

    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{adjustbox} 

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{verbatim}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{table}[!htbp]
        \centering

        \begin{tabular}{p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm}}
            \hline
            \hline
            {\LARGE Result 1} & {\huge Result 2} & {\Huge Result 3} \\  
            \hline
            (a) {\Large text} & (b) {\large text} & (c) {\normalsize text}\\ 
            \hline
            (c) {\small text} & (d) {\footnotesize text} & (e) {\scriptsize text}\\
            \hline
            (f) {\tiny text} & (g) {\huge text} & (h) {\Huge text}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}

    \end{table}\end{center}

    \end{document}
```

the code of the above table is as follows :

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}

    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{adjustbox} 

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{verbatim}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \centering
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.18}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}&&
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
            {\Large(a)} {\small text text} & & {\Large(b)} {\small text text}\\
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-b}&&
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-b}\\        
            {\Large(c)} {\small text text} & & {\Large(d)} {\small text text}\\
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-c}&&
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-c}
            \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-c}\\
            {\Large(e)} {\small text text} & & {\Large(f)} {\small text text}\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{results.}
        \label{fig:figure_A}
    \end{figure}    

    \end{document}
```